# Replacing HTML symbols or entities using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the Down Arrow with an Upper Arrow from a text whenever the mouse is over so i have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.meniu .nav").hover(function() {
        $("ul.meniu .nav:hover li").show(1000);
        $("ul.meniu .nav a:link").text(function() {
            return $(this).html().replace('&darr','&uarr');
        });
    }, function() {
        $("ul.meniu .nav li").hide(1000);
    });
});
```

It does not change the down arrow with the upper arrow it's just stands the same

HTML on Start:

```
<ul class="meniu">
    <div class="nav"><br>
        <a href="index.php">Articole &darr;</a>
    </div>
</ul>
```

After hover:

```
<ul class="meniu">
    <div class="nav"><br>
        <a href="index.php">Articole &uarr;</a>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Explain in full detail what "not working" means.  Also, show the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: how do we know what expected behavior is also?

Comment: You are targeting `<li>` with your selector but I don't see any `<li>` tags in your markup.  No wonder nothing is happening.

Comment: Wait a second.  You said it does not change the arrow, yet in your "after hover" code, you're showing us the new arrow.

Comment: That's what i want to DO ,not what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the entity in a `span` element and change the html of the `span` when the mouse event occurs.

**HTML** (note: your div should be a `li` element)

`<ul class="meniu">
    <li class="nav">
        <br>
            <a href="index.php" onmouseover="downarr()" onmouseout="uparr()">Articole <span id="arrow"></span></a>
    </li>
 </ul>`

**JS**

```
function downarr(){
    $('#arror').html("&darr;");
}

function uparr(){
    $('#arrow').html("&uarr;");
}
```